# Is there way to put macbook into a sleep without energy consumption?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep

I want behavior similar to windows when all RAM content is stored on disk and then loaded back. So I will not recharge battery after each sleep mode...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you want to use the hibernate function.

This provides a complete set of instructions:
http://woikr.com/mac/make-your-macbook-hibernate-instead-of-sleep-lionsnow-leopard/

The basic idea is:

Open Terminal.app.

Enter the following: “sudo pmset -a hibernatemode 25″

Enter you password when asked for.

Comment: Please add the gist of the linked article to your answer. Link-only answers (which this basically is) are frowned upon on this site, as they lose all value when the link target is no longer reachable.